# always true passportjs authentication

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

```
initialize: function() {

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        return done(null, {'username' : username});
    }
  ));

  // serialize sessions
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.username)
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
    done(null, {'username' : username});
  });

};

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login',
                                   failureFlash: true })
```

I got this as my Local Strategy but the authentication always fails. Please can you let me know how can I implement this situation, I mean I just wanna authenticate the user whatever is username or password is.

The POST request body is correct!

Comment: What's the name of the input field?

Comment: I'm not using 'name' attribute in my input fields, I'm sending the username and password values in the POST request in JSON. {username":"sergio","password":"pass"} and this values go well until Local Strategy function.

Comment: Then there's your problem. `The local authentication strategy authenticates requests based on the credentials submitted through an HTML-based login form.`.

Comment: OK, I will try this way then. Thanks for your time. And is there a simple way to perform this?

Comment: Ben, it's the same thing. I mean, I got the same behavior with HTML-based login. The passport.authenticate() redirects to successRedirect but when a new request is made, the request is not authenticated.

Comment: Do you have a session store setup?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63883/discussion-between-sergio-and-ben-fortune).